# select childnode in xmlnode

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlnode

I have this result from an httpGet and i want to extract some values from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:endpoint xmlns:ns4="identity.ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" description="Beskriv" id="eed9d9a0-5c8d-11ea-8778- 
9e4294fe2fb6" name="1A:1A:1A:1A:1A:1A">
  <link rel="self" href="https://10.100.10.10:9060/ers/config/endpoint/eed9d9a0-5c8d-11ea-8778- 
    9e4294fe2fb6" type="application/xml" />
  <customAttributes>
   <customAttributes>
     <entry>
        <key>Changed By API</key>
        <value />
     </entry>
     <entry>
        <key>TAG name</key>
        <value>TagNavn</value>
     </entry>
     <entry>
        <key>API Change Date</key>
        <value>2020-03-02</value>
     </entry>
     <entry>
        <key>API Changed By</key>
        <value>Mot</value>
     </entry>
    </customAttributes>
 </customAttributes>
 <groupId>aa13bb40-8bff-11e6-996c-525400b48521</groupId>
<identityStore />
<identityStoreId />
<mac>1A:1A:1A:1A:1A:1A</mac>
<portalUser />
  <profileId />
  <staticGroupAssignment>true</staticGroupAssignment>
 <staticProfileAssignment>false</staticProfileAssignment>
 </ns4:endpoint>
```

I can extract the "name" and "description" by using xmlnode.value, but im not sure how to access my custom attributes such as `<mac>` and `<groupid>`
Are they regarded as child nodes?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can share the code used to get ``name`` and ``description``?

Comment: `string name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                string description = node.Attributes["description"].Value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as (using `XDocument` class from `System.Xml.Linq` namespace):

```
// You don't need below line
// XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"path to txt file");
var macElement = xml.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name == "mac").FirstOrDefault();
// Similairly for groupid elemnt
var groupidElement = xml.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name == "groupid").FirstOrDefault();

if(macElement != null)
{
  // do something with macElement.Value
}
if(groupidElement != null)
{
  // do something with groupidElement.Value
}
```

Also call to `xml.Descendants()` is reduntant, so you could store it in variable like:

```
var descendants = xml.Descendants();
```

and reuse it.

Comment: Thank you very much!
How would this look for the <CustomAttripbutes> i have? Since they are in key,value pairs?

Comment: @Tufaaaaan You need to test it yourself. If answer helped, mark it as accepted by checking green mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Well it works for getting the value for ´mac´ but i dont know how to get the customAttributes.